# How to set up a CNAME DNS record that will be corresponding to an external website (using Amazon AWS)

Tags: cname-record, alias, amazon-route53

I created an instance of Ubuntu on EC2 and added the DNSs from goddady.

I have a page which I want to create an "Alias CNAME" to it. 
So when entering dashboard.example.com - instead of having this in the URL: app.web-app.com I'll be having dashboard.example.com.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCrsD.png
[image]

As you can see in the image - I made these changes, and whenever I enter dashboard.example.com - It opens the website app.web-app.com but changes the URL to app.web-app.com instead of keeping it like it was entered: dashboard.example.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF0Fq.png
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That it not something you can change with DNS records. Your application/web server is configured to redirect requests to `app.web-app.com`. If/how that can be changed depends on the app in question.

To learn more about this, read about how HTTP works.

Comment: Hey Sven and thank you for your response :) 
I wasn't sure that I can do that too - but my co-worker insists it's possible. That's why I asked how. 
I looked at the instructions he has (I attached an other image to my main post) and I don't understand much. 
I want to try to insert the domain name dashboard.example.com but as far as I understood - after inserting something it this text input, It will be a problem changing it. 
What do you understand from the image I attached?

Comment: This appears to be a question for the support channel of the product in question.

Comment: I inserted "dashboard.example.com" in the text-input.. and it works :) !